# Archive Runner Failed PBXCp

Tags: ios, flutter, release

When the XCode (10.2) starts Archive it fails in the very end of the process with PBXCp error and error message:

error: '/Users/stephan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-aldqclpvkpdvmwfyjhvexmwcufmi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist' is longer than filepath buffer size (1025).

I found one possible solution: Remove Flutter.framework from the build path but it did not help.

Any tips that can make my flutter app to be publish is very welcome.

Stephan

Comment: Check for the symlinks for the GoogleService-Info.plist. It is violating the archive rules.

Comment: I found the problem: The Runner.app needs to be removed from Build phases > Copy Bundle resources. After that it worked perfect and the app is now in App Store.

Comment: Thanks for your replay Sachin

Comment: Sorry @StefanC but where is Runner.app?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by removing the `Runner.app` from the `Copy Bundle Resources` folder.

then execute `flutter clean` and `flutter run`.

[image]